# Iterating list view in adb - uiautomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to iterate the list view in adb shell. I am using uiautomator, however, it seems that I have more elements than what is captured in the device. If I were to use scrolling, i would be able to access the elements. But is there anyway i do not have to scroll and simply iterate through the list elements?

[image]

This screen capture is done by uiautomator.

A snippet of my code.

```
>>> a = d(index = 0, className = 'android.widget.ListView')
>>> for i in a.child(): print i.info
```

This does not seem to be able to print anything or iterate though the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using below code to find a contact by name in phone book [which is a list element]. Hope this code helps you. At the moment I looks into each element and if the requested element is available I exit from the loop other wise I swip down. I am not sure how much it will help but it will give a basic idea. I am using appium for some UI automation. Someone, with better knowledge please guide or correct if there is any way to speed up this activity to get list of all elements of list, That shall help me also

```
public Boolean Get_PhContact_ByName(MobileDriver d, String strName){
    Boolean bFoundName = false;
    while(bFoundName == false)
    {
        List <WebElement> ContactList = d.findElements(By.id(ID_MENU_CONTACT_NAMES));
        int lstSize = ContactList.size();
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(lstSize));
        for(int iIndex = 0; iIndex < lstSize; iIndex++)
        {
            WebElement xName = ContactList.get(iIndex);
            String strNameOrNumber = xName.getText().replaceAll("(?:\\n|\\r)", "").trim();
            System.out.println(strNameOrNumber);
            if(strNameOrNumber.equals(strName))
            {
                System.out.println("Found Name" + strName);
                xName.click();
                bFoundName = true;
            }
        }
        if(bFoundName == false)
            PerformSwipeDown(d);
    }
    return true;
}


public void PerformSwipeDown(MobileDriver d)
{
    String originalContext = d.getContext();
    d.context("NATIVE_APP");

    org.openqa.selenium.Dimension size = (org.openqa.selenium.Dimension) d.manage().window().getSize(); 
    int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.8); 
    int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20); 
    int startx = size.width / 2; 
    ((AndroidDriver)d).swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 1000);
    d.context(originalContext );
}

public void PerformSwipeUp(MobileDriver d)
{
    String originalContext = d.getContext();
    d.context("NATIVE_APP");

    org.openqa.selenium.Dimension size = (org.openqa.selenium.Dimension) d.manage().window().getSize(); 
    int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.20); 
    int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.8); 
    int startx = size.width / 2; 
    ((AndroidDriver)d).swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 1000);
    d.context(originalContext );
}
```